# How can we make a JavaScript property global?

Tags: javascript, scope, callback

Please refer the below example code

```
var report = {
    chartTypes : null,
    init: function () {
        this.getChartTypes(function(data){
            this.chartTypes = data;
        });
    },

    getChartTypes: function(callback) {
        $.ajax({
            data:'',
            url:'',
            success:function(response){
               chartTypes = JSON.parse(response);
               callback(chartTypes);
            }
        });
    },
    getToolbar:function() {
        this.chartTypes --------------- NULL
    }
}
```

`getChartTypes` function load different chart types via AJAX. Therefore i put it as a callback function. Data is received successfully. But when i use `this.chartTypes` in a different function like `getToolbar` it says `this.chartTypes` is `null`. Even i have initialized the same in the starting. May be scope issue. Please advise.

Comment: This has been answered before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Comment: @NeilMunro this is *not* primarily a scope issue - it's an async issue

Comment: You seem to be assigning a value of the `chartTypes` variable inside the AJAX success callback. So before calling the `getToolbar` function which reads this variable you should make sure that the `getChartTypes` function has been called and the AJAX request has successfully finished executing.

Comment: It is neither scope nor async (although there might be an additional async problem). `this.chartTypes` simply doesn't refer to the global variable `chartTypes`.

Comment: @Alnitak This is a scope issue too

Comment: @Quentin yes, there's that too, but once that's fixed he still has the async problem

Comment: @Alnitak — Probably, we can't see how the two functions are called in relation to each other though.

Comment: Seems weird to use callbacks when you are using an OOP approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning to a variable (probably global) called `chartTypes`, but that isn't the same as `reoprt.chartTypes`. You need to assign to `this.chartTypes`, but `this` in your anonymous function won't be the same as `this` outside it, so you need to remember that value using another variable:

```
getChartTypes: function(callback) {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        data:'',
        url:'',
        success:function(response){
           callback( self.chartTypes = JSON.parse(response) );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working. But getToolbar function is called from two places. For the first time chartTypes contains the expected value. But again it is null. How can we make it global so that it does not became empty.

Comment: @manashb Maybe you have the async issue as well. Are you calling `getToolbar` before the Ajax response comes back, like `report.getChartTypes(); report.getToolbar();`, that would return null, since the Ajax callback hasn't executed yet.

Comment: Paulpro there is no async issue. getToolbar is called only after AJAX response comes back. But the AJAX function is called only once and getToolbar function is called two times. First time chartType is not empty but 2nd time it is empty.

Comment: @manashb Something else must be setting it back to null then. Once it's set it won't be changed unless it is reassigned a new value. Is your `report` object still in scope? (`console.log( report );`)

Comment: Resolved. Thanx for your reply. it is really helpful

Answer (score 0):

With an OOP approach, most developers would use a method and use `.bind()` to maintain the proper scope when the asynchronous success method is triggered. This way you do not have to worry about closures and using variables to hold the scope of `this`.

```
var report = {
    chartTypes : null,
    init: function () {
        this.getChartTypes();
    },

    getChartTypes : function(callback) {
        $.ajax({
            data:'',
            url:''                
        }).done(this._setSuccessResponse.bind(this));
    },

    _setSuccessResponse : function(data){
        this.chartTypes = data;
    },

    getToolbar : function() {
        console.log(this.chartTypes);
    }
}
```

You also need to make sure that when you call `getToolbar` that the Ajax call has also been completed.